# Accessing JSF element by id from css

Tags: css, jsf

I’ve created `<div>` using JSF.

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="loginlogo"/>
```

And I’m trying to access this div by CSS:

```
#loginlogo{
…
}
```

But I can’t access it. So, this panelgroup is rendered to this:

```
<div id="j_idt33:loginlogo"></div>
```

If I change

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="loginlogo"/>
```

to

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="loginlogo"/>
```

And css to

```
.loginlogo{
…
}
```

Then all works fine.
So, how can I access div (panelgroup) from css by id?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
[id$=loginLogo] {
    ...
}
```

This CSS syntax is using [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors), and `$=` means it will match all elements whose `id` attribute ends with `loginLogo`.